# Mi login acepta cualquier contraeña

Tags: php, sql, login, session

Por alguna razón mi sistema de inicio de sesión accede con cualquier contraseña y hacer algunas depuraciones me di cuenta que sin importar que ponga el password_verify siempre retorna true aunque la contraseña que ponga sea incorrecta, podrían ayudarme ?

Este es mi código para iniciar sesión

````
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

    $email = $_POST["email"];
    $password = $_POST["password"];

    require("conexion.php");

    try {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE correo = :correo";
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindParam(':correo', $email);
        $stmt->execute();

        $user = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        if ($user) {
            if (password_verify($password, $user['password'])) {
                session_start();
                $_SESSION['usuario_id'] = $user['user_id']; 
                header("Location: index.php"); 
                exit();
            } else {

                echo "Contraseña incorrecta. Acceso denegado.";
            }
        } else {
            echo "Correo no encontrado. Acceso denegado.";
        }
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo "Error en la conexión o inicio de sesión: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
}
?>```
````

Comment: Veo varios problemas de seguridad, primero, meter una cadena post directamente en una variable no es buena idea. Segundo, hacer un caso para cuando no existe el correo, da puerta abierta a detectar correos válidos. Dicho esto, no se que dato se guarda en el campo password de la base de datos, pero debería ser un hash y no el password en si. Dicho esto, tu SQL retorna una lista de usuarios y no un solo usuario, entonces no se que es lo que contiene $user['password'] pero podría ser cualquier cosa, deberías considerar un limit en el SQL o iterar a los usuarios devueltos.

Comment: Hace poco devolvía siempre false! Hay un [bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=76842) en password_verify de forma que devuelve siempre true si las cadenas a comparar son null. Como indica track3r esa función compara hash y el usuario no suele introducir el hash.

Answer (score 1):

No, tu script "funciona bien". Hace lo que le pides y no hay error alguno. Lo he recreado y me funciona perfectamente.

Acá tu mismo código, adaptado a mi DB y nombres de campos.

```
<?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";

    try {
      $conexion = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=pruebas", $username, $password);
      // set the PDO error mode to exception
      $conexion->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
      // echo "Connected successfully";
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
      echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
    }

    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

        echo "<pre>";
            print_r($_POST);
        echo "</pre>";

        $email = $_POST["email"];
        $password = $_POST["password"];

        try {
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE email = :correo";
            $stmt = $conexion->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->bindParam(':correo', $email);
            $stmt->execute();

            $user = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

            if ($user) {
                if (password_verify($password, $user['pass'])) {
                    echo "Bienvenido !!!.";
                    echo '<br><br><br><a href="parser">Regresar</a>';
                    exit();
                } else {

                    echo "Contraseña incorrecta. Acceso denegado.";
                }
            } else {
                echo "Correo no encontrado. Acceso denegado.";
            }
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo "Error en la conexión o inicio de sesión: " . $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

    echo '<br><br><br><a href="parser">Regresar</a>';
?>
```

Ahora, unos pequeños cambios (comentados), de muchos, que podrías ir aprendiendo.

```
<?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";

    try {
      $conexion = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=pruebas", $username, $password);
      // set the PDO error mode to exception
      $conexion->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
      // echo "Connected successfully";
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
      echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
    }

    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

        /* Siempre asegurate que tus datos lleguen bien,
        eso es lo primero que siempre hago */
        echo "<pre>";
            print_r($_POST);
        echo "</pre>";

        /* Sanitiza tus variables, mira los metodos a usar y
        averigua sobre ellos */
        $email = $_POST["email"];
        $sanitizedEmail = filter_var($email,FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);

        $password = $_POST["password"];
        $sanitizedPass = filter_var($password,FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

        try {
            /* Nunca hagas * From, toma los datos a usar, cada uno. */
            $sql = "SELECT idUser, usuario, email, pass FROM usuarios WHERE email = :correo";
            $stmt = $conexion->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->bindParam(':correo', $sanitizedEmail);
            $stmt->execute();

            $user = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

            if ($user) {
                /* Siempre guarda en variables los result o los datos de forms */
                $passBD = $user['pass'];

                if (password_verify($sanitizedPass, $passBD)) {
                    echo "Bienvenido !!!.";
                    echo '<br><br><br><a href="parser">Regresar</a>';
                    exit();
                } else {

                    echo "Contraseña incorrecta. Acceso denegado.";
                }
            } else {
                /* Acá, cada quien tiene opiniones, hasta google, amazon, netflix, etc,
                 dicen si un correo no existe en su DB */
                echo "Correo no encontrado. Acceso denegado.";
            }
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo "Error en la conexión o inicio de sesión: " . $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

    echo '<br><br><br><a href="parser">Regresar</a>';
?>
```

Definitivamente hay más cosas pero no voy a perderte si estas empezando.

Suerte !!!

Comment: Claro, lo que pasa es que Amazon, Google, etc... tienen infraestructura y desarrollo para soportar todo tipo de ataques. A uno no le queda de otra que darle la menor cantidad de información a un posible atacante, y por eso se tiende a devolver que el usuario o contraseña están incorrectos.

Comment: Yo lo se, pero vamos que si usted hace bien las cosas tiene las bases para subsanar un "ataque". Ahora, si su dominio es pajarito.com creo que le basta con las buenas practicas de cualquier lenguaje, si su dominio pertenece a una empresa o su pagina web es "especializada" en algo, los recursos para un FW u otros los debe tener. Todo es Relativo y no necesitamos ir al extremo de las cosas. Pero su punto es totalmente válido @aeportugal, saludos